# Minimizing the following objective function with matrices

Tags: graphs

I am trying to work out centrality in a network using Freeman's network centrality. I have an in degree of 83 and an out degree of 110. I want to work out the network centrality using my out degree using the following formula: 
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{g}[{C}^d ({n*})-C^{d}]}
 {[(N-1)(N-2)]}
$$

This is where 
$$
{n}
$$
is node in my graph and presuming the out- degree. Any suggestions on how to apply this formula?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question to indicate on what your problem is, exactly?  What's wrong with just plugging into the equation?  And what does it have to do with the title?

Answer (score 1):

Freeman's network centrality is a measure of a network (or sub-network). It is not talking about a specific node.